# How do you associate a workflow with a list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-online, migration

I have been migrating a list with ShareGate. The list's workflows were modified on the destination, but for the sake of quickness I deleted the list before I re-migrated it.

The workflow for the list remained intact; however, there was no way to associate the list with the workflow, or to associate the workflow with the list. **The workflow is now freestanding; it refuses to associate with a new list** because it wasn't designed as a re-usable workflow.

I've seen suggestions on using Visio 2013 Premium to convert the workflow between types, but I don't have that program right now.

Answer (score 0):

Great news: You can just create a new workflow and **copy and paste all the steps** from the old one to the new one. (This assumes you have the old and "new" workflows on the same version of SharePoint designer, likely).

The workflow steps can be copied one stage at a time.

As an additional note, it's best to start from the *last* stage and *work your way back*. This way the "Transition to Stage" step will retain its information.

I'm assuming you can use **Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C as well**, but I didn't try.